# find probabilities in question of distribution of 4 distinguishable balls between 3 people

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I got stuck verifying the probabilities I got in the 2-Dimensional probability table. would appreciate your help! I can't figure out how to find the probabilities in the X=1 and X=2 columns.

The question:"In basketball training there are 3 players and 1 trainer. one of the players is called Anthony. The trainer throw at the players all the 4 balls, such that for every ball he chooses randomly the player that will have it (Independently with other balls) let's mark: X - number of balls Anthony received. Y - number of players such that each one of them get 2 balls exactly.

Calculate the probabilities table".

Here is what I did:
[image]

furthermore, I found out that $X$~$Bin(4,\frac{1}{3})$, no clue if Y also has a special distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, because looks like most of the readers are sleepy, I'm going to publish also the answer for that.

[image]

1. firstly, let's notice that $P(Y=0)=\frac{\binom{3}{1}+\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{1}}{3^4}$. the numerator counts: there're $\binom{3}{1}$ ways to distribute the balls such that one player get all the 4 balls, and there're $\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{1}$ ways to distribute the balls such that two of the three players get the balls such that one of them gets one ball and the second one gets the rest.
2. secondly, $P(X=1,Y=1)=\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{1}}{3^4}$ because we firstly choose the single ball for Anthony, then we choose 2 of the remaining balls for one of the other players.
3. lastly, $P(X=2,Y=2)=\frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{1}}{3^4}$ because we firstly choose 2 balls for Anthony and for the remaining 2 balls we choose in $\binom{2}{1}$ ways the player that will get them.

Finally, the balded values are calculated by a probabilities-table-completing-values method.
I hope it helped anybody, Cheers.